# I need to print 94 9's as the dummy trailer

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, workday-api

I need to print a dummy trailer with 94 9;s printed continuously .
i need it as the last row of my file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest (and cheapest, in terms of processing) method:

```
<xsl:text>9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999</xsl:text>
```

---

Another option:

```
<xsl:value-of select="for $i in 1 to 94 return '9'" separator="" />
```

---

And another (requires a processor that supports XSLT 3.0):

```
<xsl:value-of select="xs:integer(math:pow(10, 94))-1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math" />
```

Comment: Cool idea, but does it work? `math:pow()` gives you an `xs:double`, and an `xs:double` only gives you about 15 digits of precision.

Comment: @MichaelKay I guess that explains why `xs:integer(math:pow(10, 94)-1)` (note the placement of `-1`)  doesn't work. But see: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGbU